# Issue with automatically injecting activities with Dagger 2

Tags: android, dependency-injection, kotlin, dagger-2

I am still pretty new to Daggers dependency injection. I am working on a new application utilizing Dagger 2 and Kotlin. I started with a basic starter app meant for building on. Within App.kt every activity is being injected automatically, which up until now is pretty cool. However I am running into an issue now with implementing Facebook and Google social logins.

When the app tries to launch Facebook or Googles sign in activities I get the error:

`"No injector factory bound for Class<external.activities.classNameHere>"`

I cannot @Provides those external classes since they do not implement the @Module annotation.

My temporary solution is to check the activity being injected before the automatic injection, and skip those external classes. This seems a little odd though, I am wondering if there is a better solution to this or if I am missing something. I can see this if statement getting pretty long over time.

```
 registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(object : ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {
        override fun onActivityCreated(p0: Activity?, p1: Bundle?) {
            p0?.let {
                if (p0 is FacebookActivity || p0 is CustomTabMainActivity || p0 is CustomTabActivity ) {
                    Log.d("KSULog", "App.kt is not injecting activity " + p0.toString())
                }
                else {
                    AndroidInjection.inject(p0)
                }

            }
        }
    })
}
```

Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to do this is quite simple.
If You look at Google Samples You will have a clear direction. Like [GitHubBrowserSample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/GithubBrowserSample)

So You will create an `interface Injectable` like this, basically a marker interface.

```
/**
 * Marks an activity / fragment injectable.
 */
interface Injectable
```

Each activity or fragment will implement this interface for example like this (in Kotlin)

```
open class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity(),Injectable {

@Inject
lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory
lateinit var baseActivityViewModel: BaseActivityViewModel

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    AndroidInjection.inject(this)
    baseActivityViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory)
            .get(BaseActivityViewModel::class.java)
}
```

}

Important lines are :

`open class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity(),Injectable`

```
AndroidInjection.inject(this)
```

Create an Activity module to contribute Activity object

```
/**
 * Module to contribute all the activities.
 */
@Module
abstract class ActivityModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    internal abstract fun contributeSplashActivity(): SplashActivity

}
```

and finally `DaggerInjector` to enable injection

```
/**
 * Helper to inject all the activities and fragments that are marked Injectable.
 */

object DaggerInjector {

    fun injectAll(application: TurtleApp) {
        DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .application(application)
                .build().inject(application)
        application
                .registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(object : Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
                    override fun onActivityCreated(activity: Activity, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
                        injectComponents(activity)
                    }

                    override fun onActivityStarted(activity: Activity) {

                    }

                    override fun onActivityResumed(activity: Activity) {

                    }

                    override fun onActivityPaused(activity: Activity) {

                    }

                    override fun onActivityStopped(activity: Activity) {

                    }

                    override fun onActivitySaveInstanceState(activity: Activity, outState: Bundle) {

                    }

                    override fun onActivityDestroyed(activity: Activity) {

                    }
                })
    }

    private fun injectComponents(activity: Activity) {
        if (activity is Injectable) {
            AndroidInjection.inject(activity)
        }
//        (activity as? FragmentActivity)?.supportFragmentManager?.registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(
//                object : FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks() {
//                    override fun onFragmentCreated(fm: FragmentManager?, f: Fragment?,
//                                                   savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
//                        if (f is Injectable) {
//                            AndroidSupportInjection.inject(f)
//                        }
//                    }
//                }, true)
    }
}
```

Uncomment the code to enable `Fragment` injection.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Using the Injectable interface as a marker was easy to implement and appears to be working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is fine but as you say it won't scale well.

You can have a look at one of the [Google Samples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/5516724bd9f02c5bffb17945d9796e29ff95c76f/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/di/AppInjector.kt) where they implement a `HasSupportFragmentInjector` interface to determine whether they want to inject an Activity.

```
private fun handleActivity(activity: Activity) {
    if (activity is HasSupportFragmentInjector) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(activity)
    }
    if (activity is FragmentActivity) {
        activity.supportFragmentManager
            .registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(
                object : FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks() {
                    override fun onFragmentCreated(
                        fm: FragmentManager,
                        f: Fragment,
                        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
                    ) {
                        if (f is Injectable) {
                            AndroidSupportInjection.inject(f)
                        }
                    }
                }, true
            )
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to inject these as you would other classes. Providing the examples in Java. Assuming you have `AppComponent` and `AppModule` classes:

```
@Component(modules = AppModule.class)
public interface AppComponent {
....
void inject(App app);
....
}


@Module
public class AppModule {
   @Provides
   FacebookActivity providesFacebookActivity() {
      return new FacebookActivity();
   }
}
```

Then you can annotate the FacebookActivity to be injected into your main activity.

```
@Inject FacebookActivity mFacebookActivity;
```

So my external activity is injected into my main activity, which in turn implements the `AndroidInjection.inject(this)` defined in the `AppComponent`. The component links to the `AppModule` which has the `@Provides` for the `FacebookActivity`.